# Ionicons working on Azure but not Localhost

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionicons

I am including Ionicons on a website I am building and they aren't showing up on my IIS Localhost Server, but they do show up on my Azure Web App. How do I make them show up on the Localhost?

Files: (only linking the .css into index.html)

```
ionicons.css
ionicons.eot
ionicons.svg
ionicons.tff
ionicons.woff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download ionic with npm or bower and include the rute in your index.html

```
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Should work , revise your local files.

ionicons.css ionicons.eot ionicons.svg ionicons.tff ionicons.woff

This files not required to display icons by http://ionicons.com/